# Dependency injection - Should I inject "utility classes"

Tags: c#, serialization, language-agnostic, dependency-injection

I am reviewing an existing code, and there is a "bean" class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyData {
 string S {get;set;}
 int I {get;set;}
 //bla bla bla
 private IStringConverter sc;
 public MyData(IStringConverter sc){this.sc=sc}
}
```

I believe it is totally WRONG to inject Utility classes / handlers or whatever in a Model class, for 2 reasons:
1) this prevent serialization
2) why? Model classes should not have behaviours.

Do you agree? (should I change classes written like this?)

Comment: Is `MyData` simply a DTO (data transfer object)?

Comment: yes, it is supposed to be stored as XML and in Session

Comment: I suppose Model with behavior stop being model

Comment: If your model really has no behaviour, then where would it use the utility class / handler or whatever? Obviously you shouldn't inject "dependencies" that by design can never be used. On the other hand, if your model converts strings then it doesn't "have no behaviour", so by your own rules your design is wrong before you even decide whether the dependency should be injected or static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could instead create a new service that operates on a DTO instance and that has its dependencies injected. That way you get the behavior out of the DTO and everything is clean again. Good architectural fit.

Answer (score 2):

Injecting a service into a DTO is probably not the best idea :)

What I would consider is using an extension method that takes the service as a parameter.

In this way the 'behavior' is separated from the DTO and serialization is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

An extension method may be the way to go, but I think this is sort-of like making your logic a compile-time singleton, which is fine if it'll never change.

So I would try something like this, as then literally everything is contract based and injectable

```
public class Poco
{
    public int Foo;
    public int Bar;
}

public class PocoUtility : IPocoUtility
{
    private IService _service; 
    public PocoUtility(IService service)
    {   
        _service = service;
    }

    public Result DoSomethingWithPoco(Poco poco)
    {
        return _service.Convert(poco);
    }
}

public class SomethingThatUsesAPoco
{
    private IPocoUtility _logicForSomething;

    public SomethingThatUsesAPoco(IPocoFactory pocoFactory,  IPocoUtility logicForSomething)
    {
        _poco = pocoFactory.CreateInstance();  
    }

    public Result DoIt()
    {
        return _logicForSomething.DoSomethingWithPoco(_poco);
    }
}
```